# window.open not working in firefox

Tags: javascript

```
alert(window.open('http://www.google.com'));
```

i tried this on firefox, and i get null, no prob in ie. any idea why?

Comment: Are there any error messages on Firebug -Console?

Comment: try window.open('http://www.google.com','google')

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It certainly works for me in firefox. Could it be a popup-blocker?

Comment: did the alert print print out null on firefox?

Comment: If you have no pop up blocker then it will print [object Window]

Comment: Note that if you drop a local file into Firefox with the original code (i.e. - non-user triggered `<script>alert(window.open(...));</script>`), Firefox does block the pop-up window and return `null`. It also presents the yellow bar across the top of the window indicating it blocked the pop-up (I'm pretty sure my settings are default).

Answer (score 0):

I tried it and also got the result is in Message box Object and also the related web page opened.

When clicking the popup blocker it will ask security warning messsage just click yes with ctrl button you will get the result.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox will return null as it's essentially a void method - you're asking it to alert(null).

window.open(''); I believe is a null method anyway - but it certainly works in FF 3.5 on 10.6

Comment: @Tom: `window.open()` blocks until the new window opens (or doesn't) and returns a reference to the newly opened window (or `null` if no new window was opened). So `alert(window.open(...));` should alert the value of the `toString()` method of the `window` object (`[object]` in IE, `[object Window]` in Firefox, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not in incognito tab

```
 let confirmAnswer = confirm("Are you sure");
 if(confirmAnswer)
    {
      window.open'https://www.google.com');
    }
```