# Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock not working in FF

Tags: asp.net, excel

I have this script in the `.cs` file and it is not working in Firefox.

```
Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock(
    "Excel",
    "<script language='javascript'>window.open('" + strFile + "','_blank', 'height=700, resizable=1, menubar=yes',false)</script>"
);
```

Comment: Please check the PopUp Blocker as in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298698/window-open-not-working-in-firefox)

Answer (score 1):

try the following:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "Exel", 
       "FunctionName('" + paramter1Name + "','" + parameter2Name + "');", true);
```